# How can I rewrite this code to use the Stream and functional API?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I've been trying to rewrite the below to use the Stream API.  I can't seem to figure out how to get to a Map (or fields) to set a key value pair for System.setProperty(k,v)

My data is just lines that have a space between them, which get split to the key and value respectively:

```
foo bar
mykey myvalue
nextkey nextvalue
```

My working source code is here:

```
try {

      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Paths.get("/path/to/file.txt"));
      while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
          String line = scanner.nextLine();
          String[] array = line.split(" ");
          if(array.length == 2){
                System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth." + array[0], array[1]);
          }
      }

} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Putting a broken sample here, though I've been all over the map (groan) trying to write it with a stream, but here is one iteration of it just to demonstrate I tried :-p

```
Stream<String> lines = null;
try {
        lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("/Users/bellis/dev/data/twitter.txt"));
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
String[] words = lines.collect((Collectors.joining("\n"))).split(" ");
System.out.println("twitter4j.oauth." + words[0] + " " + words[1]);
```

The above of course isn't correct and I Know there are much better ways to write it using functions and other common Stream idioms, but I just can't seem to get it right.
How would you recommend writing this using Stream and functional API?

Comment: @nullpointer the above attempt compiles of course, but it doesn't get through each line.  I realize now looking at it that I didn't add in my attempt to System.setProperty() -which may make my question confusing.  However, I never had anything that did what my original code did, which was to set a system property for each line in a file.

Comment: Why would any well presented question that demonstrates an attempt at the problem and a thoughtful description of the problem from someone trying to learn ever get a downvote?  Isn't the point to ask questions to gain a better understanding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your stream attempt is quite off. this is what your imperative code does.

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("/path/to/file.txt"))) {
         stream.map(line -> line.split(" "))
               .filter(array -> array.length == 2)
               .forEach(array -> System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth." + array[0], array[1]));    
} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

- maps each line to a `String[]`
- filters them to retain the elements where their length is exactly 2
- then calls `forEach` to apply a function to each and every element.